# MySQL statement not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My statement is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE division >= '0' AND division <= '10' AND voice = '0' ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will not select a user who's division is equal to 2, however

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE division >= '1' AND division <= '9' AND voice = '0' ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

will select the user

Why is this?  Thanks for any amount of help.

Comment: Why do you have it selected as strings anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If division is a number, use

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE division >= 0 AND division <= 10 AND voice = '0' ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Otherwise, convert division to number first by using [Cast Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Comment: Thank you, can you explain to me why it is that while using single quotes it doesn't work?

Comment: You can do some experiments to understand this. For example SELECT 2 > '0'; SELECT 2 > '1';SELECT 2 > 0; SELECT 2 > 1; and add cast() to it. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are storing `division` as a string.  You can try doing the conversion and comparing to numbers;

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE division+0 between 0 and 10 AND voice = '0'
ORDER BY username DESC
LIMIT 0, 10 ;
```

The only problem with this approach is that a non-numeric value (say `'A11'`) will also match, because MySQL will treat such a value as "0" in the addition.

By the way, integer comparisons to strings do work, although I do not recommend using them.  Consider that:

```
select  (2 <= '10') as IntToString, ('2' <= '10') as StringToString
```

returns:

```
1    0
```